# What does ‘ng’ mean in hacking toolkits names?

Tags: vocabulary

In various toolkits and program’s names there is an ng prefix or postfix. For example: “Airckrack-ng”, “Recon-ng”, peass-ng” and so on.

I’ve tried looking up the abbreviation and reading about those tools but couldn’t find any explanation.

Comment: Next generation. In frontend it also refers to Angular.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exclusive to hacking toolkits, and stands for **"Next Generation"**. You can verify this by going to https://www.aircrack-ng.org/ , and hovering over the "ng" in the description, where they have helpfully used an abbr tag.